# JMeter's HTTP Request file throws 404 error

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-404, performance-testing

[JMeter HTTP Request - 404 ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf3x9.png)

While I run my jmx file, It throws a 404 error for one of the HTTP Request file. Screen shot is given above.

Can anyone please suggest some solution for this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an [embedded resource call](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) for the [`/favicon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) URL which is not found therefore the request fails.

You should raise an issue as [HTTP 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) errors might cause [SEO consequences so your site will rank lower](https://www.custard.co.uk/404-errors)

If you don't care about the embedded resources errors you can add the [next line to *user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous):

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Comment: Now the error changed to **401** from **404**. Pls check the attached screen shot from my above shown question for reference